# Add a new column after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using pandas to process a csv file with the following structure

```
date, student, score, outof
20040601,mark,80,100
20040601,jack,40,100
20040602,mark,60,100
20040602,jack,30,100
```

I want to group the above data by date and then calculate the percentage for each date and then plot it.

I am able to do groupby, by using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("csv_file")
grouped_by_date = data.groupby('date')
```

I am also able to calculate the percentage for each line using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("csv_file")
date['percentage'] = data['score']/data['outof']
```

But I am not able to do it on the grouped data. How to do it on the grouped by data?

**Edit**:

The following is the desired output that I want

```
date, percentage
20040601,60
20040602,45
```

Comment: What would be the desired output (how would it differ from `date['percentage']` as you calculated it for the full dataframe?)

Comment: @joris Just edited the question to add the desired output

Comment: Can you see this as the mean of the percentage you calculated for the full dataframe per group (so `data.groupby('data')['percentage'].mean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
data['percentage'] = data.score/data.outof
data.groupby('date').mean()
```

Yields:

```
          score  outof  percentage
date                              
20040601     60    100        0.60
20040602     45    100        0.45
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is what I would do:

```
>>> df.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)
>>> df['percentDate'] = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: np.mean(x['score']/x['outof']))
>>> df
Out[391]: 
         student  score  outof  percentDate
date                                         
20040601    mark     80    100           0.60
20040601    jack     40    100           0.60
20040602    mark     60    100           0.45
20040602    jack     30    100           0.45
```

First of all, since you want to set the values into the dataframe as a column, it's nice to set the index according to what you group-by: it makes setting the values later on easier (to me).

Second, Observe that I have used numpy's `mean()` function: since score/outof will return a column of observations (one row per student), you have to average out over that.

Comment: From this how can I get the expected output? (ie) only one line for each date?

Comment: Only run the right-hand side command (`df.groupby(level=0)...`).